# How TO create a BOOTABLE USB stick on Windows 8

Tags: 12.04, installation, usb

i need to boot ubuntu from my usb drive.i did not face problems when creating with pendrive linux but nothing is displayed on the boot screen?

Comment: This question has been answered before: http://askubuntu.com/questions/312927/booting-13-04-64-bit-pendrive-in-uefi-freezes-immediately-after-loading-ramdisk

Comment: Your question title and question content are referring to two different things. Are you having trouble creating a bootable usb stick or are you having trouble booting from an already created usb stick? Which one is it? Also please be more verbose. Do you get any error messages? Describe in detail what you have already tried (eg change BIOS settings, dissable UEFI, etc). Just edit your questions and add as much relevant information as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could also give an alternative tool like: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/ a try. Has worked like a charm for me loads of times.